# iPhone encoding of non latin characters

Tags: iphone, encoding, utf-8, character, non-latin

I am trying to parse a JSON response of a GET request. When the characters, are latin no problem.

However when they are not latin the message doesn't come out correctly. I tried greek and instead of "πανος" i get "& pi; & alpha; & nu; & omicron; & sigmaf;"

The code I use for parsing the response is:

```
NSString *responseString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:responseData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

NSLog(@"response %@", responseString);




// array from the JSON string
NSArray *results = [responseString JSONValue];
```

When I try to read the response from a website using ajax, everything is fine. The same applies when trying to send a GET request to the application servers with data from iphone. So when i transmit data to the server and read it from the website everything is fine. When i try to show the same data in the app, "Houston we have a problem".

Any clues?

**EDIT:** To avoid misunderstandings, it's not an issue of HTML, I just point out that for some readon utf-8 characters here are encoded correctly and automatically eg. "&pi" will be converted to "π", however objective c doesn't seem to do this on its own

Comment: I believe it's the website's problem (not ObjC) returning the HTML entities.

Comment: You are not stating which JSON framework you are using, but to my best knowledge thay all support non-roman characters perfectly. So you should look in either the http data delivered by the server, or in your display routine.

Comment: @KennyTM The website works fine, so I don't think we have a problem there..

Comment: @Claus I am using The json parser I use is [json-framework](http://code.google.com/p/json-framework/), however even before the parsing as you can see i print the response with NSLog after I have already encoded it using UTF-8 encoding and nothing happens

I think the JSON parsing doesn't really matter since i previously try to encoded it

Comment: @tappy: Have you dumped the **raw data** received from the website?

Comment: @tappy Don't rely on what's printed by NSLog as you have not full control over the encoding used for printing. I'll add my vote to @KennyTM's suggestion of dumping the raw data before _any_ parsing or encoding is performed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a confusion I think.

`&pi;` is an ***HTML entity*** which is unrelated to *text encoding* like UTF8 / Latin.

Read [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_XML_and_HTML_character_entity_references) for details about...

You need a parser to decode these entities like the one previously mentioned by Chiefly Izzy:

```
NSString+HTML category and method stringByReplacingHTMLEntities
```

Answer (score 0):

Look at Cocoanetics NSString+HTML category and method stringByReplacingHTMLEntities method. You can find it at:

https://github.com/Cocoanetics/NSAttributedString-Additions-for-HTML/blob/master/Classes/NSString%2BHTML.m

Here's a pretty decent list of lot of HTML entities and their corresponding unicode characters.

Comment: I've checked the source and thanks for the interest but unfortunately it's not html text that i am trying to parse as a response. HTML was referenced to show that when i try to read the same response from the web application everything looks fine (in the webpage).
Moreover the source includes greek encoding but greek was also an example as a non-latin language..

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this snippet of code:

```
  NSString *responseString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:responseData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

  NSString *decodedString = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:[responseString cStringUsingEncoding:[NSString defaultCStringEncoding]]];


  NSLog(@"response %@", decodedString);


  // array from the JSON string
  NSArray *results = [decodedString JSONValue];
```

Answer (score 0):

I have faced the same problem, but I solved it by changing the JSON parser. I have started using the SBJSONParser, and now I am getting the appropriate results. This is the code snippet, I have used

```
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init] autorelease];
[request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlString]];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];

NSData *returnData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:nil error:nil];
NSString *returnString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:returnData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
SBJSON *parser=[[SBJSON alloc]init];
NSArray *JSONData = (NSArray*)[parser objectWithString:returnString error:nil];
```